# Is this a bug with arrows using |- (the line goes too far)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am using arrows in a diagramme I am making with tikz, but it does something wierd.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (Goal) at (2,2);
\draw (-.3,2) -- (Goal);

\coordinate (Flat1) at (0,0);
\draw[red,-latex](Flat1) |- (Flat1|-Goal);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It will give you this :

[image: arrow going to far]

You can notice the red line goes too far, and if you remove the `-latex` the problem disappears or if you change the arrowhead shape the incorrect length changes.

Do you know how to correct that ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why using `|-` twice? Use simply `\draw[red,-latex](Flat1) -- (Flat1 |- Goal);`

Comment: True ! Plus it does solve my problem. @Sigur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\draw[red,-latex] (Flat1) |- (Flat1|-Goal);`

is the same as

`\draw[red,-latex] (0,0) |- (0,0|-2,2);`

is the same as

`\draw[red,-latex] (0,0) |- (0,2);`

is the same as

`\draw[red,-latex] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0,2);`

So the arrowhead is put on a zero length line segment. This has two problems:

- The arrow head directions is undefined and
- The `shorten >` the arrow automatically makes is inverted(again in an undefined direction)

Correct code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Goal) at (2,2);
\draw (-.3,2) -- (Goal);
\coordinate (Flat1) at (0,0);
\draw[red,-latex] (Flat1) -- (Flat1|-Goal);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Black line and red arrow]

Answer (score 1):

Another way for doing the same thing commented by @Sigur

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \coordinate[label=90:G] (G) at (2,2);
        
        \coordinate[label=-90:F] (F) at (0,0);
        
        \draw[red,-latex] (F) -- (F|-G) coordinate(aux) ;
        \draw ($(aux)+(-0.3,0)$) -- (G);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]